# where should I put the images file?

Tags: html, eclipse

I am trying to develop a web application where main concern is the Image processing, but I am stuck with the very basic problem, the images are not loading at the run time of my html page. I have tried and put image files in the src folder but no use the html page keep showing blank on that image area. Where should I put the images files so that the html can directly access to them or what necessary provision I need to do? I am novice in eclipse , so bit elaboration needed..
[image: here is the ss attached]

Answer (score 1):

Your current method is assuming the image 'Untitled.png' is in the same folder as your 'index.html' page.

I have a header image which is used on 4 html pages. Here's how I do it.

```
MyWebsite
  Images
    top-logo.jpeg
Styles
  styles.css
index.html
career.html
education.html
about.html
```

And then:

```
<img src="Images/top-logo.jpeg" />
```

The image is contained in the Images folder which is on the same level as the web pages. So you select the folder, then select the image.

Have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp for more information on files paths.

Answer (score 0):

Try with absolute path, for example if the image is in say location C:\Documents:\Image.jpg, you may add it like,

```
<img src="C:\Documents:\Image.jpg" alt="Image" height="200px" width="200px">
```

Or, in this case, pasting the images inside the "rahul" package might help.

Comment: actually after completion of this project we need to upload it to app engine, so i need to know knw which is the by default folder of resources ...

Comment: Well, it surely be the install location of the app engine.